# What motivates someone to key a Tesla

Tags: motivation

**Background**
Over the last few months there have been multiple reports of random strangers keying Teslas.

I am interested in understanding the mental state of of the person carry out the act? I have already read the following article https://cleantechnica.com/2019/10/05/what-motivates-someone-to-key-a-tesla/ which is quite insightful . But I am looking for a generic predisposition that plagues these peoples mind - Are there any day to day examples of the same ? Do we all have these predisposition though of varying degrees (examples) ?

How can one change their mentality to not fall prey to performing these actions?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the literature on aggressive behavior, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggression. There are many potential causes for such an act. In terms of generic predispositions, consider personality types (e.g., low Agreeableness), but don't overlook the importance of context and culture (e.g., high wealth inequality).

As to the final question, self-help questions are out of scope for this forum.

Comment: I wouldnt tag this as a self-help question. I would assume self-help is wherein I am requesting for help to improve myself. Is this questions directed towards understanding human behaviour?